# Dynamic change max values in select with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu, onchange

I have 2 selects like this:

```
<select id='select1'>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
<option value='4'>4</option>
<option value='5'>5</option>
</select>


<select id='select2'>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
<option value='4'>4</option>
<option value='5'>5</option>
</select>



<select id='select3'>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
<option value='4'>4</option>
<option value='5'>5</option>
</select>
```

In this example, 5 is a max so if I select the value 2 in select1, I want my select2 and select3 to have as max value : **5 - 2 = 3** to get this final output:

```
<select id='select2'>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
</select>

<select id='select3'>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
```

Of course, the behaviour should be the same regardless of the items I choose.

Comment: this appears to be a list of requirements rather than a question?

Comment: show us what you have tried ?

Comment: What else you want apart from this??

Comment: You cannot keep the list items static if they are dynamic, you need to dynamically create the subsequent list based on the option selected in select 1, so other than your initial select 1 other selects would be dynamically populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#select1").change(function(){
        $("#select2 option, #select3 option").show();
        var maxValue = 5 - $(this).val();
        for (var i = 5; i > maxValue; i--)
        {
            $("#select2 option[value='"+i+"'], #select3 option[value='"+i+"']").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/9DAE4/3/

Comment: This is exactly what i needed, combined with some php loops to write it for n select, it worked as it should have, thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var sel = $('#select2,#select3');
$('#select1').change(function () {
    var val = this.value; //get value
    sel.val('1').find('option').show(); //set value 1 to select 2,3 and show all options
    sel.find('option[value="' + val + '"]').nextAll('option').hide(); //hide nextAll values next to max value
});
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/7vE7L/)</kbd>

---

Reference

[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

[.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

[Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

---

<kbd>[**Updated fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/7vE7L/2)</kbd>

```
var sel = $('#select2,#select3');
$('#select1').change(function () {
    var val = 5 - this.value;
    sel.val('1').find('option').show();
    if (val === 0) {
        sel.find('option').hide();
    } else {
        sel.find('option[value="' + val + '"]').nextAll('option').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to use onChange event on select of first select box.This event will call a javascript method and that method will dynamically create/modify other select boxes.